# My home router is giving my Bridged vm adaptor a diffrent dynamic ip

Tags: network-programming

Hi so i am trying to setup a little LAN in virtualbox, i have zeroshell running as the router and a windows 10 VM. I have configured my first ethernet adaptor for zeroshell to use a bridged adaptor, then giving it a dynamic ip address, to my understanding it should be the same ip address to my host machine(I did it at tafe and it was working fine) but m router seems to be giving it its own ip address, i have also setup a second ethernet adaptor to be an internal networl adaptor with a static IP of 192.168.10.1, So i can ping my router from my windows 10 vm and i can ping the bridged ethernet adaptor but i cant ping my host machine or get access the internet can soemone please help?

Comment: this is not programming issue, but administrators or super user (configuring virtualbox netowrk).

Comment: This looks a network setup problem rather than a network programming one. As such, it may be [closer to topic over at superuser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).